# How to convert format to12 HRS instead of 24hrs SQL

Tags: sql, time, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT 
Warehouses.Name, CONVERT(TIME,AirwayBillTrucks.CheckOutTime) AS CheckOutTime,
```

Comment: SQL server or Oracle or MySQl ? What is the column type ? Please elaborate more on it.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  And what version?

Comment: Its SQL server 2012, airwaybilltrucks column was showing DD-MM-YYY-HH-MM-SS that's why I converted to TIME because I only needed HH-MM-SS but now I need to display it into 12hrs format instead of 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server -
This will fetch you 12hr format

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Your_column_Name, 100) AS 12_hr_format
```

To show just the time

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Your_column_Name, 100), 7) AS time_in_12hr_format
```

OR simply use the code **108**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Your_column_Name, 108) AS time_in_12hr_format
```

Conversion - 
**100** - `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)` 
**121** - `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)`

You can see all the type of format conversion [here at Microsoft CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: thanks Perfect but I only need to show time not the date how do I get rid of it. ?

Comment: Yes It helped, thank you Pirate X,  Its an awesome community here at stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Server 2012+

```
Select Format(GetDate(),'hh:mm:ss tt')
```

Returns

03:55:30 PM